# Change color of string in Visual Studio 2010's text editor for C++

Tags: string, visual-studio-2010, colors

I'm curious if anyone can tell me how to make std::string color itself like it is a primitive. I've been using 2012 on my home machines and I really love it and have gotten used to having them colored, at a company I'm interning for I am using 2010 and can't figure out what I would change in fonts and colors. Thanks, also... sorry for the pretty menial question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching for a template, for example in this page
[studiostyl](http://studiostyl.es/)

then you have to go to Tools -> Options -> Import and Export Settings